# UriFormatException getting caught in exception handler for ASP .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I've added exception handling to my Asp .Net Core application to log any unhandled exceptions. I am getting unhandled UriFormatExceptions within the middleware due to what appears to be traffic from various web crawlers targeting non-existent endpoints. I am not sure how to fix this, or at least elegantly silence it so it does not show up in my telemetry. In general, I'd like to ignore traffic hitting endpoints not defined by my application.

**Exception logged**

[Unhandled exception][UriString][https:///favicon.ico][Exception]
[System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.]

Stacktrace:

```
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, String routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteConstraintMatcher.Match(IDictionary`2 constraints, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, RouteDirection routeDirection, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)]
```

**Exception Handler**

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerApp =>
{
    exceptionHandlerApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
        IExceptionHandlerPathFeature exceptionHandlerPathFeature = 
        context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

        string uriString = null;
        uriString = context.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
        
        Logger.EmitLog(
            "Unhandled exception",
            "UriString",
            uriString,
            "Exception",
            exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error);
    });
});
```

Comment: If the crawlers are hitting endpoints you don't have, could you not just add an `if` check in your exception handler and silently return `404`? Another idea would be to add a middleware for everything, and if the request was for a non-existent endpoint, short circuit right there and return the `404`... this avoids an expensive exception.

Comment: Could you please share the `code snippet` where you are trying to retrive the URI Segment?